# How to dynamically bind data source using parameters in ssrs report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In Data Source, establish Connection string like this

```
="Data Source=" & Parameters!DatabaseServer.Value & ";Initial Catalog=" & Parameters!InitialCatalog.Value
```

but I got error during processing of the connection string expression of the data source.Kindly help me to solve this issue

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you miss UserName or Password in Connection string ?